# How to get correct position of a checkbox in a scrollable listView?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a scrollable listview that has 2 textViews, 3 imageButtons and 1 checkBox in each row.

In the Header of the listView, I have a delete button just above the column containing all the checkboxes of the listView.

I have to perform the delete operation of objects in the listView when 2 or more checkBoxes are checked randomly by scrolling the listView and thereafter the delete button at the top is clicked.

But the problem is that i am not getting the correct poition of the checkbox that was selected. Moreover, sometimes i get the correct position but still the object to be deleted passed is wrong. Hence the entire functionality is affected maybe due to the scrolling nature of the list.

Should i take the position in the holder of the adapter class and also bind the state of the checked or unchecked checkbox with my object.

And should I use checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener() or deleteButton.setOnClickListener().
If i use the latter one, then how to get all the corresponding objects of the list whose checkboxes were checked before pressing the delete button?
And where should all the related code be placed..in the listAdapter class or in the activity?

Please help me find a solution to this problem..

Comment: This is a classic ListView problem and has been discussed here time and again. Please use search better.

Answer (score 0):

first of all in your getView() method you should set a specific Tag to each checkBox. For example: `check1.setTag(position)` then you should implement both OnCheckBoxChangeListener for your checkBoxes and OnClickListener for your delete button. As you know setting of onCheckBoxChangeListner have to be in getView() method. Then you add positions of list that their checkBox is checked to the a ArrayList with the help of getTag() method of chechBoxes in onCheckedChanged() method.

Answer (score -1):

Try `getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {}`

Comment: Not sure how this relates to the above question.